# osx - dyld: Library not loaded Reason: image not found - Python Google Speech Recognition API

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, speech

When I try to use the Google Speech Rec API I get this error message. Any help?

> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/flac/1.3.1/lib/libFLAC.8.dylib
>   Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/speech_recognition/flac-mac
>    Reason: image not found

I'm using PyCharm.

I have tried copy pasting and uninstalling and reinstalling but to no avail. HELP :) My whole project is to get the user to say something, and have google translate translate it and have it say the answer. I have the translating and speaking covered, but the Speech Recognition is what I am having trouble with now. Thanks in advance

Here's more error messages.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File >"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line >162, in _run_module_as_main
>      "**main**", fname, loader, pkg_name)
>    File >"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", >line >72, in _run_code
>      exec code in run_globals
>    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site->packages/speech_recognition/**main**.py", line 12, in 
>      audio = r.listen(source)
>    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site->packages/speech_recognition/**init**.py", line 264, in listen
>      buffer = source.stream.read(source.CHUNK)
>    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site->packages/pyaudio.py", line 605, in read
>      return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames)
>   IOError: [Errno Input overflowed] -9981

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you must have homebrew installed.

Second, after homebrew is installed, you'll want to install flac:

```
brew install flac
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - I just forgot to install Homebrew

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer? I'm getting exactly the same error. How did installing Homebrew solve the issue?

Comment: @abmirayo From what I know, Homebrew installs things that Apple finds excessive and does not need in every computer, so it is not included in the normal OSX. Homebrew basically has the random files you might need for example the Flac file. Tell me if you need help installing home-brew. What are you using it for? Just asking.